# Prove that the coordinate vector of an element $u$ of a vector space $V$, with respect to a finite $\beta$ basis, is unique.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the coordinate vector of an element $u$ of a vector space $V$, with respect to a finite $\beta$ basis, is unique.

**Attempt**

Let $a_1,\: \ldots ,\: a_n,\: b_1,\: \ldots ,\: b_n$ scalars and $\beta = \{x_1,\: \ldots ,\: x_n\}$ a basis for $V$.

Let $u \in V$. Suppose that the coordinate vector, $[u]_{\beta}$, has two representations:
\begin{align*}
[u]_{\beta}=\left( a_1,\ldots ,\: a_n \right) = \left( b_1,\ldots ,\: b_n \right) 
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
u=a_1 x_1 +\dots + a_n x_n= b_1 x_1 + \dots + b_n x_n
\end{align*}
Then it follows that
\begin{align*}
0= (a_1 - b_1)x_1 + \dots + (a_n-b_n)x_n
\end{align*}
By the definition of linear independence, it follows that $(a_1-b_1)=\ldots=(a_n-b_n)=0$, which means that $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$, i.e., the representation is unique.

Comment: Looks fine to me. However, you may wish to call $[u]_{\beta}$ the representation of $u\in V$ with respect to the basis $\beta$ to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Ok, thank you...

Comment: While the logic is good, I suggest removing this part: " that the coordinate vector, $[u]_{\beta}$, has two representations: $$[u]_{\beta}=( a_1,\ldots ,\: a_n) = ( b_1,\ldots ,\: b_n)$$ where". That part is nonsensical for several reasons. First $(a_1, \dots, a_n), (b_1, \dots, b_n)$ are representations of $u$, not $[u]_\beta$. $[u]_\beta$ itself is just another name for those two (once you have proven them equal, and therefore can apply a notation to their common value). And in saying $( a_1,\ldots ,\: a_n) = ( b_1,\ldots ,\: b_n)$ you are prematurely claiming the result you are proving.

Comment: Ok, I understand.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Attempt: Suppose that $\beta_1=\left\lbrace u_1,\: u_2,\: \ldots ,\: u_n\right\rbrace$ y $\beta_2=\left\lbrace u_n,\: u_1,\: \ldots ,\: u_{n-1}\right\rbrace$ are two ordered bases of $V$. Then for any $x\in V$ there exist unique scalars such that \begin{align*}
x=a_1u_1+a_2u_2+\ldots +a_nu_n=a_nu_n+a_1u_1+\ldots +a_{n-1}u_{n-1}
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
[x]_{\beta_1}=\left( a_1,\: a_2,\: \ldots ,\: a_n \right)\; \text{y}\; [x]_{\beta_2}=\left( a_n,\: a_1,\: \ldots ,\: a_{n-1} \right)
\end{align*} Note that $x$ is uniquely written as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_iu_i$

Comment: and, therefore, the coordinates with respect to an ordered basis are unique.

Comment: There was no need for that. You missed my point. Your logic was good as it was. The only problem was in the way you explained it. You had a correct idea you were trying to explain, but knowing what you meant, you didn't pay close enough attention to what you actually said, and wrote down something that was nonsensical. When I said to remove that quote, I meant exactly that. If you remove those exact words and leave the rest of the proof alone, the result will be a comprehensible and correct proof. In the new proof, it is not even clear what you are going for. (BTW `\vee` = $\vee$.)